# How to merge features by 2 attributes in arcmap

Tags: python, arcmap

[image: Demo how it's going to be]

I have some features with a lot of attributes on a layer
How I can merge 2 or more features (objects/polygons) into one by attribue CAD_NUM and then by VP_PP attribute and get sum of third attribute SHAPESTArea (look at the screenshot).

I don't know Python, especially how it works inside arcmap, can you provide code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find arctool called Disolve and it's solved by it